# Sending requests from Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Here is a simplified version of some Flash code I have been using to get username of the person playing the game:

```
var req:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
req.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
req.load(new URLRequest(baseURL + "php/account.php?getUsername"));
function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
    if(e.target.data == "Guest") {
        LoadingText.text = "Welcome, Guest!"
    }
    else {
    LoadingText.text = "Welcome, " + e.target.data + "!";
    }
}
```

php/account.php?getUsername just gets the username from a PHP session variable and outputs it.

Using something like Tamper Data for Firefox, I can see the request being sent from Flash and can even edit it if I wanted.

This approach feels very slow compared to other online games, and when trying to reverse engineer other games to see how they manage something like this, for some games, requests wont show up in Tamper Data.

So I wonder, are there any alternative ways to send requests in Flash which are faster and more efficient? I don't need anything fancy such as sending post data or editing the referral URL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably other games use socket connections. This is reason why you don't see request in Tamper Data and why they have better performance.

In case of socket connection you open connection to server once and you can make as many requests as you wish.

With HTTP, TCP connection is opened and closed for each request this affects performance.

With socket connections you can avoid HTTP protocol completely, you can design your protocol much lighter than HTTP. In fact no one uses HTTP when you need high performance.

See flash socket documentation here: [Socket](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html)

P.S.

For high performance it is better to use UDP instead of TCP but flash sockets are limited to TCP so you don't need to take care of this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I'll look into using sockets and let you know how it goes.